# How to rescue OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2::CallbackError?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, callback, oauth-2.0, omniauth

I am building a Rails application with [Omniauth](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth) for log in service.To authenticate Google I am using [OmniAuth Google OAuth2 Strategy](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2).

When user clicks 'allow access' button everything works fine.But when user clicks 'no thanks' button the below error is raised.

```
OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2::CallbackError
```

I have tried adding the below rescue code in application controller.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2::CallbackError, :with =>
    :omniauth_callback_error_handler

 protected

 def omniauth_callback_error_handler
  redirect_to init_sign_in_users_path
 end
end
```

But no luck. Any idea?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This happens because the authentication happens in a middleware so your controller is not involved in it. This is [where the exception is raised](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth-oauth2/blob/master/lib/omniauth/strategies/oauth2.rb#L66) and the called code is [this](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/blob/master/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb#L446)

I think you can handle this kind of error by defining a callback in OmniAuth initializer with this kind of code

```
OmniAuth.config do |config|
  config.on_failure do
    # your handling code invoked in the context of a rack app
  end
end
```

Otherwise there is [a commit](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/commit/d02f9d58f70f132c856199470f94b93c852d9bb0#L3R2) of three months ago which introduce this behavior

```
def redirect_to_failure
  message_key = env['omniauth.error.type']
  new_path = "#{env['SCRIPT_NAME']}#{OmniAuth.config.path_prefix}/failure?message=#{message_key}"
  Rack::Response.new(["302 Moved"], 302, 'Location' => new_path).finish
end
```

which states that on errors your user is redirected to `/auth/failure` with an error message, so you should be able to define a route for that path and handle it in your app. Keep in mind that this won't happen [in development mode](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/blob/d02f9d58f70f132c856199470f94b93c852d9bb0/lib/omniauth/failure_endpoint.rb) so you need to try it in other envs. If this doesn't happen in production try to upgrade your omniauth gem to version 1.1.0

Comment: 1000.times.do 
  puts "Thank you very much!"
end

Comment: I got this working using `OmniAuth` instead of `Omniauth`.  Looks like the capitalization has changed.

Comment: To test the failure in development mode you can add this:
`OmniAuth.config.failure_raise_out_environments = []`

Comment: In case you are not able to land on the action in development environment, then check https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth/wiki/FAQ#omniauthfailureendpoint-does-not-redirect-in-development-mode

Answer (score 67):

You can set the on_failure proc in the omniauth initializer in an even cleaner fashion:

```
OmniAuth.config.on_failure = UsersController.action(:oauth_failure)
```

Comment: This code works great in production evironment. However, if you change your UsersController#oauth_failure code in development environment, you'll not see any changes. The soundar's code based on Proc is better in development and works as expected in development.

Comment: @mcmlxxxiii has a good point. When I went with this approach I had issues in test when using Spork. This line was causing my UsersController and ApplicationController (UsersController's superclass) not to get reloaded on each test run. Going with soundar's solution fixed this. Note that I didn't have to do the string constantize step; I was able to reference the UsersController directly in the Proc.new block because it only gets evaluated later.

Comment: one gotcha is that this doesn't send the provider name directly to the controller, you need to do something like `request.path.split('/').third` to get it

Comment: This code on Rails 6 will result in a DEPRECATION WARNING as the controller will be initialized in the initialization process. This version avoids this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10743341/727

Answer (score 18):

I have solved this problem with the Fabio's first suggestion.

```
OmniAuth.config.on_failure = Proc.new do |env|
  UsersController.action(:omniauth_failure).call(env)
  #this will invoke the omniauth_failure action in UsersController.
end
```

In my UsersController

```
class UsersController < ActionController::Base
  def omniauth_failure
    redirect_to init_sign_in_users_path
    #redirect wherever you want.
  end
end
```

Comment: where do i have to put that above code   Omniauth.config.on_failure = Proc.new do |env|
  "UsersController".constantize.action(:omniauth_failure).call(env)
  #this will invoke the omniauth_failure action in UsersController.
end

Comment: put the code in config/initializers/omniauth_failure_callback.rb file. I suggest you to use the peter's code as its really clean.

Comment: @soundar, though peter's code is cleaner, your code works in development environment as expected in development environment. So +1 to your answer too.

Comment: as @mcmlxxxiii mentioned, this is better for development and test. Especially if you're using Spork, the other solution will prevent UsersController (and any controllers it inherits from) not to get reloaded on each test run. But I didn't have to call `"UsersController".constantize`. I was able to directly call `UsersController.action` because this code is in a block that gets executed later.

Comment: Same as other answer: one gotcha is that this doesn't send the provider name directly to the controller, you need to do something like `request.path.split('/').third` to get it

Answer (score 2):

There's a configuration to use `/auth/failure` instead of raising an error.

I use OmniAuth 1.2.2 and when I checking the FailureEndpoint I found the code is like [this](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/blob/master/lib/omniauth/failure_endpoint.rb#L20):

```
def call
  raise_out! if OmniAuth.config.failure_raise_out_environments.include?(ENV['RACK_ENV'].to_s)
  redirect_to_failure
end
```

And the `failure_raise_out_environments` is defined [here](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/blob/master/lib/omniauth.rb#L37):

```
def self.defaults
  @defaults ||= {
    # other configurations
    :failure_raise_out_environments => ['development']
  }
end
```

The environment can be configured so the solution is easy. I use Rails so I put below code in an initializer file:

```
OmniAuth.configure do |config|
  # Always use /auth/failure in any environment
  config.failure_raise_out_environments = []
end
```